# Symfony2 prePersist/ preUpdate Listener Notice

Tags: doctrine

I've got a problem using Doctrine/Symfony2 prePersist/preUpdate Listeners.

There are Two Entities in a ManyToOne Relationship (one Location can be referenced by many Persons). I built a Form, where I do some AJAX-Stuff to help the user select a Location for a new Person, that already exists. Therefore, I am using an "entity_id" Form-Field.
I would also like to give the user the possibility to create a new Location for a new Person that does not exist in the Database. This is handled by a second field in the form, where the user can Insert the Name for the new location.
When persisting the Entity of Person, I am checking if there is a Location referenced that exists in the Database. If not, I am generating a new Location-Entity. This is (in short) my prePersist-Lifecyclecallback in the Entity-Class Person:

```
public function prePersist() {
   if($this->ort == null) 
       $this->ort = new Ort($this->ortsname);
}
```

This works perfectly, when I am creating a new Person. The problem is the updating-Procedure. So when there was as location connected to the person before, and I want to create a new Location by the same procedure (with a preUpdate-Listener), I get a Notice like:

```
Notice: Undefined index: 000000004a0010250000000058426bec in ...Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php line 983
```

I do not know how to solve this. I think it's got to be something with the Location-Object, that was before referenced to the Person object, but I do not know how to tell the Entity-Manager that the Location-Object, referenced to the Person, is a new Entity.
I also tried this with a Listener-Class like:

```
if( $entity instanceof Person) {
    if( $entity->getLocation() == null ) {
         $entity->setLocation( new Location( $entity->getLocatioName() );
         $em->persist($entity->getLocation());
         $em->flush();
    }
}
```

The $em->persist ... stuff should not matter, because in the mapping the "cascade={persist}" notation is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll run into trouble with `preUpdate`.  There are two things that mean `preUpdate` isn't the best event-handler for situations like this:

- Changes to associations of the passed entities are not recognized by the flush operation anymore.
- Any calls to EntityManager#persist() or EntityManager#remove(), even in combination with the UnitOfWork API are strongly discouraged and don’t work as expected outside the flush operation.

(These two points are taken from the bottom of this section: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/events.html#preupdate)

Furthermore, as `preUpdate` is called in the middle of Doctrine's flush operation, calling `flush` again will cause problems.

Therefore, I'd recommend that you use `onFlush` instead: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/events.html#onflush

If you do this, you'll need to tell Doctrine that the Person entity has changed once you've added the Location to it.  It's also slightly more complicated to get the changed Person object itself.  Try something like this in your `onFlush` handler:

```php
public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $args)
{
    $em = $args->getEntityManager();
    $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

    foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates() AS $entity) {
        if ($entity instanceof Person) {
            if ($entity->getLocation() == null ) {
                $entity->setLocation( new Location( $entity->getLocationName() ));

                // have to tell Doctrine that the Location has been updated
                $cmf = $args->getEntityManager()->getMetadataFactory();
                $class = $cmf->getMetadataFor(get_class($entity));
                $args->getEntityManager()->getUnitOfWork()->computeChangeSet($class, $entity); // don't use recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet here - that doesn't care about relationships
            }
        }
    }
}
```